# Why do I get this error on python and how do I fix it? (loops and strings)

Tags: python

My code suppose to take a string to a function and then switch the caps of each char in there from h to H and E to e
but I somewhat get an error in my if s
why is that?

This is the error messege:

```
chr = str[i]
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

My code is:

```
def CapsChanger(str):

    i = str[0]
    for i in str :
        chr = str[i]

        if((ord(chr) > 46) and (ord(chr) < 91)):
            str[i].upper()

        if((ord(chr) > 96) and (ord(chr) < 126)):
            str[i].lower()
    print str       

str = raw_input()

CapsChanger(str)

input()
```

Comment: `for i in str` iterates over actual chars, no indicies. It's not needed to do `chr = str[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `for i in str`, in each iteration `i` represents that actual character, not the index. So you don't need to do `chr = str[i]` - `i` is already that character.

Comment: BTW, Python has no concept of "character": Everything is a string ;).

Comment: An explanation as to the error itself may help too. `str[i]` in this case is equivalent to `str['0']` which will confuse the evaluator. `string indices must be integers` is complaining about receiving an index that isn't an integer.

Comment: ok thanks! 
also thats a nice fact , im new to this language so I do have my falls here

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

def invertCase(text):
    ## Creating a list where results will be stored
    results = list()
    ## This will contain the abc in upper and lowercase: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
    abc = string.lowercase + string.uppercase

    ## Looping each letter of the received text
    for letter in text:
        ## If the current letter of the loop exists in our abc variable contents, it means it's a letter and not a symbol or space
        ## So we can apply upper() or lower() to the letter.
        if letter in abc:
            ## If the letter is currently uppercase, then we turn it into lowercase
            if letter.isupper():
                results.append(letter.lower())
            ## If the letter is currently lowercase, then we turn it into uppercase
            else:
                results.append(letter.upper())
        ## The current letter of the loop is not in our abc variable so it could be anything but a letter
        ## So we just append it to our results list
        else:
            results.append(letter)

    ## Once the loop finishes we just join every item in the list to make the final string and return it
    return ''.join(results)

print invertCase('SoMeOnE Is hAvING fUN')
```

Output:

```
sOmEoNe iS HaVing Fun
```

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: this one would be problomatic for me since I did not learn about list I only got to the point of arrays and loops and functions

Comment: @TotalyNotUbisoft no problem. Still, I hope it helped in some way.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a `string`, not `index`. If You need `index` use `enumerate`:

```
for idx, i in str:
    print idx, i
```

Insted of `ord(chr)` use `string` that represent a letter.

Insted of two if conditions use `Chained Comparisons`.

```
def CapsChanger(str):
    out = []

    for idx,chr in enumerate(str):
        if 'Z' >= chr >= 'A':
            out.append(chr.lower())

        elif 'z' >= chr >= 'a':
            out.append(chr.upper())
    print(''.join(out))
```

Comment: i tried doing so but It didnt really change the caps inside the string does .update() have a part in this?

Comment: @TotalyNotUbisoft `str[i].upper()` will return an uppercased version of `str[i]` but it won't change `str[i]` itself. Moreover, strings in Python are immutable, so you will have to build a new string from the original; you won't be able to change it in-place. -- edit -- ninja'd. :P

Answer (score 0):

The variable i is already a 1 character string because the for loop processes strings this way.  Also, when you call str[i].upper(), it needs to either be assigned to something, or printed out, otherwise the character is never actually changed in place.  .lower() and .upper() also have a behaviour which already checks the range for you, and returns the same characters.  Eg. if it already uppercase, or a number, upper() will just return the same character.

Your function can be simplified as follows:

```
import sys
def CapsChanger(str):
    for i in str:
      sys.stdout.write (i.lower() if (i.upper() == i) else i.upper())
    print

str = raw_input()
CapsChanger(str)
```

`sys.stdout.write` is used to avoid printing out extra spaces.  The ternary operator is used to switch case in one shot:

```
<value1> if <condition> else <value2>
```